# "Array" is displaying in dropdown instead of values fetched from database

Tags: php, html-select

code snippet from html_form_class

```
<?php
$frmStr = $frm->addSelectList(
                      'city',
                      $city,
                      true,
                      '',
                      '--- Select City ---',
                      array(
                          'class' => 'dropdown-style5',
                          'id' => 'city')); 
echo $frmStr; ?>
```

code snippet from seachcar.php

```
   $city = $db->select('City','City_Name');
foreach($city as $row)
{
 $row;
}
```

"Array" is displaying in dropdown instead of values fetched from database
Please Advice!

```
function addSelectList($name, $option_list, $bVal = true, $selected_value = NULL,
            $header = NULL, $attr_ar = array() ) {
        $str = "<select name=\"$name\"";
        if ($attr_ar) {
            $str .= $this->addAttributes( $attr_ar );
        }
        $str .= ">\n";
        if ( isset($header) ) {
            $str .= "  <option value=\"\">$header</option>\n";
        }
        foreach ( $option_list as $val => $text ) {
            $str .= $bVal? "  <option value=\"$val\"": "  <option";
            if ( isset($selected_value) && ( $selected_value === $val || $selected_value === $text) ) {
                $str .= $this->xhtml? ' selected="selected"': ' selected';
            }
            $str .= ">$text</option>\n";
        }
        $str .= "</select>";
        return $str;
    }
```

html output of addSelectList function is

```
  <select name="city" class="dropdown-style5" id="city">
  <option value="">--- Select City ---</option>
  <option value="0">Array</option>
  <option value="1">Array</option>
  <option value="2">Array</option>
  <option value="3">Array</option>
```

Comment: Can we see all your code?  I can't tell a damn thing without seeing the whole `addSelectList()` function.  If you're using a framework or something, what is it?

Comment: Dude, really? Edit your post and put that stuff in there so its readable.

Comment: @searsaw i did it for you now please check and let me know

Comment: Please tell us the outputted HTML (the value of `$frmStr`)

Comment: Again, put it in your question.

Comment: If you say the problem is that `Array` is displayed in the `select`. Why isn't `Array` in the outputted HTML? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Consider turning on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Put it somewhere in the beginning of all your code.

Comment: @StijnMartens
now please check I have updated the code for php section and html output clearly showing the Array

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($city);` and tell us the results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rebuild the array of cities:

```
$city = $db->select('City','City_Name');
$city_rebuild = array();
foreach($city as $row) {
    $city_rebuild[] = $row['City_Name'];
}
$city = $city_rebuild;
```

Comment: blank output as well as its my generic class function to hard code it wont work for me at other places

Comment: Okay I took that in consideration. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do echo of array. Something is wrong in your abstraction objects. You must iterate on array to show up its values.

Answer (score 0):

function addSelectList creates a "[dropdown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)" (actually a select element)

You need to remove the html from the function output.

**Edit 1**
I was confused as to what you were going for.  In your foreach($option_list... you need to know what keys are available in the $option_list array and what you want to appear in the select dropdown.

Comment: @Mubbashir... I misunderstood, but I know know what you're trying to do.  First  we need to know what the values available in the array are.  Do something like print_r($option_list); and let me know what it says.

Comment: values are 'Lahore', 'Karachi', 'Multan','Hyderabad'

Comment: That's not what print_r returns.  We need to be able to see the structure of the array

Comment: I've solved my problem thankyou so very much for anticipation :)

Comment: Please post your solution so we can benefit from it. Thats the idea of this community.

Comment: @StijnMartens I just did, I was asleep by that time was very much tired